# Angular undefined error when assigning array to another array with Mock data

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, jasmine

I am trying to unit test a component where I am getting 'Groups' data using data resolver class. here is the code for it.

```
export class GroupsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  group: IGroup;
  groups: IGroup[];

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private titleService: Title,
    private userService: GroupsService
  ){
     this.titleService.setTitle('Home | Groups');
     this.groups = [];

     this.groupsComponentDataSubscription = this.activatedRoute
        .data
        .subscribe(
       data => {

        if(data['groupsResponse']){
           this.groupsResponse = data['groupsResponse'] as IGroupsResponse;
           this.groups = this.groupsResponse.groups;
       }
      })
    }
  }
```

For testing, I am using mock data for 'groupsResponse' as below:

```
let mockGroups: IGroup[] = [{
  groupName: "testGroup1",
  description : "group1 detail",
  apiRoles: ["foo", "bar", "monitoring"],
  kafkaClusters: [{
     clusterId: "cluster1",
     topics: ["foo", "bar"],
     connectClusters:[{
       clusteId: "testCluster1",
       connectorNames: ["foo", "bar"]
     }]
  }]
 },
groupName: "testGroup2",
  description : "group2 detail",
  apiRoles: ["foo", "bar", "foobar"],
  kafkaClusters: [{
     clusterId: "cluster2",
     topics: ["foo", "bar"],
     connectClusters:[{
       clusteId: "testCluster2",
       connectorNames: ["foo", "bar"]
     }]
  }]
 }
]

let mockGroupsResponse: IGroupsResponse = {
   groups: mockGroups
}
```

Then I am passing this mock value for ActivatedRoute as below:

```
let activatedRouteMock: any;

beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {

activatedRouteMock = {
  data: of({groupsResponse: [mockGroupsResponse]})
};

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
 imports:[...],
 declarations: [GroupsComponent],
 providers:[..., {provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: activatedRouteMock }]
}).compileComponents
```

My mock data for resolver is read successfully. However, The problem I am facing is while trying to assign groups array from the response to local variable.

```
constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private titleService: Title,
    private userService: GroupsService
  ){
           ...
           ....
           this.groupsResponse = data['groupsResponse'] as IGroupsResponse; // groupsResponse is assigned as mock data -- console.log -> [{ groups: [object], [object]]
           this.groups = this.groupsResponse.groups; // here, not able to set this.groups array from groupsResponse. (undefined)
       }
      })
    }
  }
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong with mock. In real case scenario where I am getting data from resolver using http as Promise, I don't have any issue setting the array. However, My test is not working

Answer (score 0):

Removes the API calls from the constructor and moves them inside ngOnInit.

the constructor should only be used to inject dependency. [Ref](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit-in-angularjs/)
constructor is fired before your mock services are ready.

Comment: I am able to get the mock data in the constructor but the problem is in assigning array from the returned object to another array .. below line is not set as expected

//this.groups = this.groupsResponse.groups

Comment: just a wild guess could this be the issue:  
 data: of({groupsResponse: [mockGroupsResponse]}) should be
  data: of({groupsResponse: mockGroupsResponse })

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the issue lol. I was passing as array ..